# If you help someone in combat and you lose, do you both get the 'bad stuff'

Tags: munchkin

If you are facing a monster, but don't have enough fighting power to win in combat, you can persuade another player to help you. This adds their combat power to yours.

What happens if the monster still wins? (For example, if a third player pulls out a card that raises the monster's power over your combined power).

Does the 'bad stuff' only happen to the original player, or does the helping player have to suffer this as well?

If the bad stuff does happen to the helping player, do they both roll separately to 'run away', or do they run away as a team?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both players must roll to run away separately, and any player that fails to run away suffers the bad stuff.

From the [official rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf)

> If two players are cooperating and still can’t defeat the monster(s), they 
>   must both Run Away. They roll separately, and each player chooses in what 
>   order to Run Away. The monster(s) CAN catch them both.

and

> If you fail to Run Away from a monster, it does Bad Stuff to you, as 
>   described on its card.